# Lock scollbar when mouse down and unlock when mouse up

Tags: javascript, jquery

iam trying to lock the scroll bar with the current position when mouse down event and also need to unlock when mouse up event

```
$('#table td').on('mousedown', function(){
$('#container').scrollLeft(0);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var keys = {37: 1, 38: 1, 39: 1, 40: 1};

function preventDefault(e) {
  e = e || window.event;
  if (e.preventDefault)
      e.preventDefault();
  e.returnValue = false;  
}

function preventDefaultForScrollKeys(e) {
    if (keys[e.keyCode]) {
        preventDefault(e);
        return false;
    }
}

function disableScroll() {
  if (window.addEventListener) // older FF
      window.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
  window.onwheel = preventDefault; // modern standard
  window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = preventDefault; // older browsers, IE
  window.ontouchmove  = preventDefault; // mobile
  document.onkeydown  = preventDefaultForScrollKeys;
}

function enableScroll() {
    if (window.removeEventListener)
        window.removeEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', preventDefault, false);
    window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = null; 
    window.onwheel = null; 
    window.ontouchmove = null;  
    document.onkeydown = null;  
}

$(document).ready( function(){
$('#table td').on('mousedown', function(){

        disableScroll();

});

$('#table td').on('mouseup', function(){

    enableScroll();

});
});
```

check [this solution](http://jsfiddle.net/shandanjay/t3c0bfn2/)

based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily)

hope this helps

Comment: please check that fiddle . the scroll is not still working when the contents drags

Comment: iam trying to lock the scroll bar whic position that maintains when dragging

Comment: it's really depends on the text selection. One option is you have to disable the text selection inside the table